# Persistent parameter in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller, persistence

is there any way to persist (preserve) parameters in Rails controller? It should be passed to every action, then to every view and every link.

Example situation:
I have entity A with its controller. Besides, I have another entity B which is dependent on A. I need to access the "parent" A entity very often, so I'd like to have it still as

`http://some_url/b_controller/b_action?a_entity=xyz`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do everything from your controller, using a combination of `before_filter` and `default_url_options` :

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_a_entity

  def set_a_entity
    @a_entity = params['a_entity']
    # or @a_entity = Entity.find(params['a_entity'])
  end

  # Rails 3
  def url_options
    {:a_entity => @a_entity}.merge(super)
  end

  # Rails 2
  def default_url_options
    {:a_entity => @entity}
  end

end
```

This doesn't solve the problem of setting the initial value of `@a_entity`, but this can be done from anywhere (view, controller, etc).

If you want this parameter passed around in multiple controllers, you can replace `MyController < ApplicationController` with `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` and it should work as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't used your solution after all because I don't need to persist the option for every controller forever, but basically it does the job. Thanks and sorry for late accept.

Comment: That solution works also inside a specific single controller. Thank you very much.

Comment: @F.Filippi thanks for the heads-up, I modified my answer because the single controller case is indeed more useful.

Comment: So, My question is, how do I make the url_options available in the paths that are created in the views. The paths created in the views seem to ignore the url_options set in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

why not put it in a session parameter then?

```
session["a_entity"] = "xyz"
```

that way you can access it in all your other controllers too until you clear it or it expires.

more info here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: I'd like to have my app RESTful. Also I find the session a bit tricky because of stored URLs which can lead to different results with different sessions.

Comment: could you show us an example? it's kinda hard to imagine how your app works with a few general ideas